# Intialization of 2d array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

```
bool subsetSum(int arr[], const int &n, const int &sum)
{
    bool T[n + 1][sum + 1];
}
```

The above code is used to generate an 2d Boolean type array in subsetSum, but the compiler says both "n" and "sum" must be constant. How can I create an 2d array in my function just like ordinary stack variable like “double” and “int”?

Comment: Is it possible not using pointers?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _just like ordinary stack variable like “double” and “int”_ ?

Comment: you mean in the sense of not needing pointers?

Comment: I mean not using pointers@Apollo

Comment: Yes, Because the code can be complied in some other compilers but not on mine. @Apollo

Comment: And it is a good thing it doesn't compile on your compiler. Then you get to learn how to properly create dynamic arrays (using `std::vector`).  That syntax that compiles on some compilers is fake -- it isn't real C++ code, but unfortunately it fools new programmers into believing it is valid code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @PaulMcKenzie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring an array like you are atempting is not standard C++. The sizes used to declare the array must be known at compile time. Hence, the compiler reports that as an error. Some compiles support variable length arrays (VLAs) as an extension but they are not standard C++.

For dynamic arrays like that, use `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<std::vector<bool>> T(n+1, std::vector<bool>(sum+1));
```

It takes away need to deal with dynamic memory allocation and deallocation from user code.